# C# Gridview, rearrange

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I really didnt know what to put to the title so sorry about that. I have 2 colums where i list files from 2 folders. Now what i would like to do is to give a user ability to rearrange the files by clicking on one file in one column and then on the other file in other column. The application merges these two files together.

Just onother option would be just use datagrid and its drag and drop functionality (one column is static and one rearrangable with drag and drop or something) but doing it this way isnt really what i would like..

So, all options are welcome..

EDIT: 
Using WinForms, it doesnt have to be gridview, just i couldnt think of anything else..

Comment: GridView is ambigious. Please specify UI framework (WebForms, WinForms or WPF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just create two `DataGridView`'s (or `ListView` if you prefer), the first listing the files in the folder `A` and the second listing the files in the folder `B`.

Then allow to select just one row at a time in both grids (`MultiSelect = false`, `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`) and add a button called "Merge Selected", that simply merges the file selected in the first grid with the one selected in the second grid.

Comment: Thnx, i should of explaned my applications more. The whole meaning is to merge these files automatically by those A and B folder listings. Its going to loose the point when user has to do them one by one (:

Comment: @hs2d: ah ok, so you need to arrange their order to build `file A` - `file B` matchings to merge... well then allow multiple selection and allow reordering of datagrids rows adding for example up-down arrow buttons (like in many designer collection editors)

Comment: Yes, i havent thought about adding up/down arrows. I think i'l consider it as an option if wont get any better ideas..

Comment: @hs2d: up-down arrows really simplify the work... Reordering using drag-n-drop is not so easy but there's some example on the Internet e.g. [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/dragdroplistviewreorder1.aspx).

Comment: @hs2d: another example of reorderable ListView --> [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822483/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 2 list boxes linked to each folder so that the use can scroll up/down to select the file they need
2. Have button "Merge Files" which gets enabled when an item from both listboxes are selected.
3. When user clicks on "Merge Files" have a confirmation box to make sure its not clicked my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're talking about [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), as [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) has been deprecated.

In the designer, make sure `SelectionMode` on the DataGridView is set to `CellSelect`.  Then in properties --> events, double-click the `SelectionChanged` event to create a new method which handles that event.

Add this code to the method:

```
private DataGridViewCell _lastCellSelected = null;
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 0)
    {
        _lastCellSelected = null;
        return;
    }

    DataGridViewCell selectedCell = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0];
    if(_lastCellSelected == null || selectedCell.ColumnIndex == _lastCellSelected.ColumnIndex)
    {
        //User clicked first cell
        _lastCellSelected = selectedCell;
    }
    else
    {
        //User has clicked two cells from different columns
        string filename1 = _lastCellSelected.Value;
        string filename2 = selectedCell.Value;

        //TODO: "Merge" files here

        _lastCellSelected = null;
    }
}
```